# Open IPython at startup in Sublime Text 3

Tags: ipython, sublimetext3

I am trying to customize the Sublime Text 3 settings for Python files in a Python.sublime-settings file. What I want to do is have two columns in the layout and automatically open the IPython console in the right column on opening a python file in sublime text. I have SublimeREPL installed for IPython.

I can get the layout split in 2 columns using,

```
"Layout": 2
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to set IPython to open automatically.

Any ideas? Thanks.